# Subcomponents in stateless components

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I've googled quite a lot, but couldn't find the answer to this, makes me feel so stupid.

In stateful components I usually write some parts as small functions like

```
renderSmth = () => (
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
);
```

and then use it by call in main render method.

As for stateless components when i write sub-parts the same way i.e.

```
const renderSmth = () => (
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
);
```

eslint gives me warning for no-multi-comp. As far as I understand, writing this this way

```
const smth = (
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
);
```

should give the same outcome, just the usage will be slightly different - not a function call.

Do i understand right, that stateless components recalculate on each re-render? Is the last way legit or are there any drawbacks?

Comment: It seems that this is because `renderSmth` is defining a new component; `smth` just uses existing components; it doesn't take in `props`, for instance. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-multi-comp.md has some detail on how you can get around this, for instace, using `ignoreStateless`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, if you declare smth as a variable instead of a function, you won't be able to access props.

If you don't need to use props inside smth, then that's the way to go. Otherwise you can declare it nested inside your main function, like this:

```js
renderSmth = (props) => {
  const smth = (props) => (
    <div>...</div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      smth(props)
    </div>
  );
};
```